# Java extend parameterized interface with additional type parameter

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Moving my post scriptum to the top instead, so people don't waste their time if I've posted this to the wrong site: I couldn't decide on whether this belonged here or on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. If the latter is deemed more appropriate I'm happy to see it moved.

I have a parameterized interface with a method that takes a `Consumer` and, if a certain condition holds true, invokes it with `this` as a parameter. Otherwise it returns `this` (to make it chainable on the call site, as you may already have gathered):

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> {

  boolean someCondition();

  default SomeInterface<T> someMethod(
      Consumer<SomeInterface<? extends T>> action) {
    if (someCondition()) {
      action.accept(this);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Now I would like to extend this functionality by adding another parameter so I can return additional information to the caller:

```
public interface SomeInterfaceExtended<T, U> extends SomeInterface<T> {

  U getAdditionalInformation();

  @Override
  SomeInterfaceExtended<T, U> someMethod(
      Consumer<SomeInterfaceExtended<? extends T, U>> action) {
    if (someCondition()) {
      action.accept(this);
    }
    return this;
  }
}
```

This of course doesn't work since the two methods have the same erasure. I ended up not extending the interface, but rather defining all the same methods and having the "extended" interface's implementors delegate to an instance of the "basic" interface:

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> {

  boolean someCondition();

  default SomeInterface<T> someMethod(
      Consumer<SomeInterface<? extends T>> action) {
    if (someCondition()) {
      action.accept(this);
    }
    return this;
}
...
public interface SomeInterfaceExtended<T, U> {

  U getAdditionalInformation();

  boolean someCondition();

  default SomeInterfaceExtended<T, U> someMethod(
      Consumer<SomeInterfaceExtended<? extends T, U>> action) {
    if (someCondition()) {
      action.accept(this);
    }
    return this;
  }    
}
...
public class SomeClass<T> implements SomeInterface<T> {
  @Override
  public boolean someCondition() {
    // whatever
  }
}
...
public class SomeClassExtended<T, U> implements SomeInterfaceExtended<T, U> {

  private final SomeClass<T> delegate;
  private final U additionalInformation;

  public SomeClassExtended(SomeClass<T> delegate, U additionalInformation) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.additionalInformation = additionalInformation;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean someCondition() {
    return delegate.someCondition();
  }
}
```

This all feels a bit clumsy/bloaty. Is there a way I can more efficiently (loc-wise) share the implementation?

Comment: I suggest you try to post that on the code review section:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Might be better to just call the second one `someMethodExtended` instead of trying to override the other `someMethod` with different types.